# Any idea what this error means in SVN?

Tags: java, svn

Sending        example.java
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:
example.java
Unwanted TAB in file: example.java

I tried to revert my changes, and then even just adding one extra character, I'll seeing this error. Very strange! Any help would be greatly appreciated O_O

Comment: You have to talk to the administrator of your subversion repo. Obviously whatever pre-commit hook the server is using doesn't like the format of your Java file.

Comment: You have a pre-commit hook - a script that checks your file before commit - that has seen that your code contains one or more tab characters (at least that's what the message appears to say).  You should edit the file in some way to remove the tab, or speak to a local expert about the pre-commit hook.  It could be that your editor is somehow fiddling with the whitespace in your file, hence the message appears even when you make a small change.  Can you inspect the file in a basic editor like vi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your SVN server does some pre-commit processing that does not allow tab characters in java source files. Try configuring your IDE to replace tabs with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Your SVN server has [pre-commit rules](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) which check the validity of your commit (including commit comments). These rules are usual used to enforce things such as including branch numbers in commit comments for traceability purposes. It seems that you are violating a pre-commit rule by having a TAB character in your example.java file. Try removing all TAB characters from example.java and re-committing.

An odd rule I must admit. Kind of taking the spaces vs. tab characters argument to the extreme.....

Comment: weird thing is even if i revert all my changes, and try to recommit by just adding one extra character of any nature, i'll still get the same error, so I don't quite understand why TAB would be raising an issue...or maybe the policy was added after the last commit?hmm...

Comment: The commit hook is located in $REPOS_ROOT\hooks\pre-commit.tmpl (or possibly pre-commit.bat). If you have access to the svn server you can check the modification stamp as if you can't commit an existing file without any added tabs it's either a new rule or something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys. It was a formatting issue after all. I don't know how it happened, but solved it in the end by gong to Eclipse -> Source -> Format

Cheers!